# Disk Image Tools for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, image

I have a Windows Server 2008 X64 machine that I need to swap the boot drive on.  I'd like to use a disk image/restore utility to make an image of the boot partition and restore that to the new drive.

Does anyone know of a free or reasonably priced tool that can do this?  I know that Acronis True Image will do it, but you need to have their server product to restore images of a server OS and it's prohibitively expensive ($850).

Thanks,
jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clonzilla is pretty cheap: free

http://clonezilla.org/

Sounds like for your purpose you can just create the bootable CD, grab an external USB hard drive (or network location, etc.), backup your image, do what you need to do and then restore it.

Comment: Does Clonezilla allow me to directly clone one drive to another or do I need to do a backup first and then restore that to the target drive?

Comment: You can clone from drive to drive. We have used successfully at works numerous times.  In fact it has worked with out a flaw where Ghost has failed.

Comment: THanks...testing this now with some virtaul machines and seems to be working great.

Answer (score 1):

Win2k8 comes with a replacement for the old NTBackup called Windows Server Backup, which can do "image backups".

You can find out more about Windows Server Backup [in this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754572(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ShadowProtect Server edition, its fully functional for 30 days and is probably one of the best imaging products I've used. Request the full trial by email, and they will send you a link for the .iso to boot from and restore the image.

http://www.storagecraft.com/trial_downloads.php